# Detect whether a product is new. Shopify Liquid

Tags: shopify, liquid

I want to be able to display the text 'New' alongside a product that was added recently in shopify.

Something like `{% if product.date_added > ten_days_ago %}New{% endif %}`

**EDIT**

Seems like there is some undocumented objects of `product` which I found out by console logging `{{ product | json }}`.

```
{{ product.created_at }}
{{ product.published_at }}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```
{% assign product_date = product.published_at | date: "%s" %}
{% assign current_date = 'now' | date: '%s' %}
{% assign difference = current_date | minus: product_date | date: "%d" %}

{% if difference < 10 %}
    New
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I figure I can use %j for the date which is the day of the year, literally, if it's jan 1st the day will be 1.

Comment: @Buts yep, that will work as well. The code will be the same but it will remove that final date filter `date: "%d"`.

Comment: Actually you're right with `"%s"` because it is seconds since! this means i won't have to worry about crossing over years.